# rspec - rails routes to wrong controller when using namespaces but only sometimes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes, namespaces, capybara

Please bear with me, I've tried a lot of things before posting this and I'm not sure what exactly you need to be able to help me with this. Just let me know and I'll update the code.

I have an issue with randomly failing specs so I ran the `--bisect` command with rspec to find out why the specs are failing. 
It seems that if I run 2 specs in a certain order the specs fails.

The command I'm running is this:

```
be rspec './spec/features/scheduling/scheduler_spec.rb[1:3:1,1:3:2:1,1:3:2:2:1,1:3:2:2:2,1:3:3,1:3:4,1:3:5,1:3:6]' './spec/requests/api/v1/shifts_spec.rb[1:1:2]' --seed 16251
```

The routing engine seem to think that the following link should go to the `Api::ShifsController` when it instead should go to `ShiftsController`:

```
= link_to new_shift_path(date: date.to_date, user_id: user.try(:id)), remote: true do
    = fa_icon "plus fw"
```

routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'landing_page#index'
  ..
  resources :shifts, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  # API
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: 'json' } do
    scope :v1 do
      resources :locations, only: [:index] do
        resources :shifts, only: [:index]
      end
    end
  end
```

Gemfile:

```
ruby '2.4.1'
..
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.2'
gem 'capybara', '~> 2.16'
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 3.7.0'
..
```

The error I'm getting is this:

```
Failure/Error: raise ActionNotFound, "The action '#{action}' could not be found for #{self.class.name}"
AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
The action 'new' could not be found for Api::ShiftsController
```

Note! This only happens sometimes when running the specs. It never happens in development or in production. Well, I haven't experienced yet.
If I comment out the line `resources :shifts, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]` from the routes file, everything goes back to normal.
I have no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably caused by Rails autoloading getting confused between ShiftsController and API::ShiftsController (or Shifts and API::Shifts models if they exist) depending on which is used first in a test, and then thinking it doesn't need to load the other.  To fix this try requiring the specific controller and/or model definition files, being used in each spec, at the top of the spec files.

Like this:

```
# spec/features/scheduling/scheduler_spec.rb
require "#{Rails.root}/app/controllers/shifts_controller"

# spec/features/api/shifts_spec.rb
require "#{Rails.root}/app/controllers/api/shifts_controller"
```

Comment: @karlingen It's not a `rspec-rails` issue, it's an issue with how the Rails class autoloader works and only occurs when there are name collisions in different namespaces.  Not much that can be done about it.